# How disabled edge runtime in next14 for next-auth, prisma adapter and getSession?

Tags: next.js

I'm facing issues while building my app.

```
    npm run build
    
    > build
    > next build
    
      ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
       - Environments: .env
    
      Creating an optimized production build ...
    Failed to compile.
    
    ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js
    Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime 
    Learn More: 
    
    Import trace for requested module:
    ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js
    ./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.jshttps://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation
```

How can I resolve the issue with the Edge runtime? If necessary, I may opt to disable it as it is not required.